# Add exec to "start menu" and CLI

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, shortcuts, tar

I just downloaded Sublime Text, I used tar to extract it and the software was inside without the need to install it like a package or something.
I would like to add a shortcut by typing "sublime_text" in the terminal and being able to access it from the "start menu". A .desktop file is provided, I tried to put it in the Applications folder with admin privileges, I see it with the right icon, but when I run it nothing happens.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

The sublime_text program is located at the following path /opt/sublime_text_3

Thanks!

Comment: If you open the terminal, does running the command `/opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text` open the text editor? On the side: you may also put your .desktop files under .local/share/applications (.local is a hidden folder in your home). That way, you do not need root permissions to put it there or edit it. On the other hand, it will show up only in your account.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for your answer. The command runs fine in the terminal. And for some reasons it now works in the start menu. I'm note sure what happened. Thanks for the tip about the local application folder, i'll remember that.